# typescript Property 'formData' does not exist on type 'Event'?

Tags: typescript

I am getting this error message when trying to compile my typescript code:

```
typescript Property 'formData' does not exist on type 'Event'?
```

```
formElem.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    // on form submission, prevent default
    e.preventDefault();

    // construct a FormData object, which fires the formdata event
    new FormData(formElem);
});

formElem.addEventListener("formdata", (e) => {
    
    let data = e.formData;        // this is where the error occurs.
    .
    .
    })
```

I tried to search for an `Event` type which is a sub-type of `Event` but i was not lucky.
What i am doing wrong here?Any Suggestions are welcome

Comment: How exactly are you firing the `formdata` event?

Comment: @zhulien i edited the question to include the firing of `formdata` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're using the sample from [MDN's formdata event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/formdata_event). The event type you're looking for is [FormDataEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormDataEvent) which provides the `formData` property. If you check the browser compatibility table, however, you'll notice it is not supported in all browsers(namely Safari).

As I see, Typescript currently doesn't support this event type yet, but they have an open issue related to it [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36217). You can verify it is missing in the [general definitions](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts) as well.

At this stage, you either have to introduce a custom type(like the one in the issue provided above) or annotate the event as `any`. Once again, this won't work on Safari.

Here is a [somewhat related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62021611/is-there-no-submitevent-interface-in-typescript) which may help you.